# Inconsistent CodeIgniter routes.php behaviour

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I'm using CodeIgniter's `routes` file to remap short urls to their relevant controller functions.

Oddly enough, some urls get remapped, while others don't, even though the syntax is identical.

Below is my `routes.php` file. The remapping of `info/web` and `info/rent` works as expected, while `info/cell` and `info/hotel` gets redirected to my 404 function.

Any idea what could be causing it?

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = 'home/four_o_four';
$route['robots.txt'] = 'home/robots';

$route['info/cell'] = "articles/tags/cellphone";
$route['info/rent'] = "articles/tags/car-rental";
$route['info/web'] = "articles/tags/internet-abroad";
$route['info/hotel'] = "articles/tags/hotel";
$route['articles/tags/(:any)'] = "articles/articles_by_tags/$1";
$route['articles/destination/(:any)'] = "articles/articles_by_destination/$1";
$route['articles/(:any)'] = "articles/show_article/$1";
```

Comment: The order of sequence matters.  If incorrect, the higher routes will over-ride the ones below.

Comment: I think that problem in controller not in routes table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-routing one URI to another re-routed URI.

```
$route['info/cell']            = "articles/tags/cellphone";
$route['info/rent']            = "articles/tags/car-rental";
$route['info/web']             = "articles/tags/internet-abroad";
$route['info/hotel']           = "articles/tags/hotel";
$route['articles/tags/(:any)'] = "articles/articles_by_tags/$1";
```

You are supposed to route *from* a **URI** *to* a **Controller/Method**, not to another URI.

Just route them all *directly* to each corresponding Controller/Method...

```
$route['info/cell']            = "articles/articles_by_tags/cellphone";
$route['info/rent']            = "articles/articles_by_tags/car-rental";
$route['info/web']             = "articles/articles_by_tags/internet-abroad";
$route['info/hotel']           = "articles/articles_by_tags/hotel";
$route['articles/tags/(:any)'] = "articles/articles_by_tags/$1";
```

[Routes Documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: Thanks, Sparky. I changed it and it now works, but I still don't understand how come in the original format, it did work with info/rent & info/web, and didn't work with info/cell & info/hotel...

Comment: @einav, you'd have to dig into the CodeIgniter Core to figure that out.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Since I'm supposed to redirect to a Controller/Method, and the dash isn’t a valid character in a class or method name, it didn't accept the routing rules that had dashes, and did accept the rules without dashes.
Thanks again!